# Sqlite database with single row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create a sqlite database table having single row and multiple columns.
Each time entire row will be updated.

In the sqlite i can create the table but first time updating entire row is not working.

The update entire row works only after the first INSERT command. Instead of doing first time INSERT command is it possible to execute UPDATE  command as soon as the table is created?

I am doing following steps:

> $ sqlite3 test.db

```
sqlite> create table company (Id int primary key not null, name text, age int);
sqlite> update company set id=1, name='test', age=30;
sqlite> select * from company;
sqlite>
```

Here select statement is not returning anything.

Is there any restriction in SQL to use the UPDATE command very beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be ignoring how sql works. You perform an update of nothing and expect that a row magically exists after that.

You have to do an insert first.

Answer (score 1):

You want to try

```
insert into company values (1, 'test', 30);
```

in order to have *one* record.

`update` only changes what is alread there, it cannot be used to create (that is: insert) new records.

Now, after having created your first record, you can  change it with a

```
update company set age = 45 where id = 1;
```

Comment: Contrary to the accepted answer, you gave an example, which deserves an upvote.:-)